# Finding the determinant of a special matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, recurrence-relations, determinant

I was given this problem in my Linear Algebra 1 homework:

Calculate the determinant of a general matrix of order $n\times n$ that looks like this:

$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
a+b & b & \cdots & \cdots & b \\
a & a+b & b & \cdots & \vdots \\
\vdots & a & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & b \\
a & a & \cdots & a & a+b \\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

There is a given hint which is to find a recurrence relation and solve it.

What I did so far:

I simplified the matrix using the elementary operation of row addition that doesn't change the determinant to this:

$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
a+b & b & b & \cdots & \cdots & b \\
-b & a & 0 & 0 & \cdots & \vdots \\
0 & -b & a & 0 & \cdots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & -b & a \\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

And then by using the definition of a determinant according to the last row I developed it into this:
$$
b \cdot
\left|
\begin{matrix}
a+b & b & b & \cdots & \cdots & b \\
-b & a & 0 & 0 & \cdots & \vdots \\
0 & -b & a & 0 & \cdots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & -b & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
\right|
+ a \cdot
\left|
\begin{matrix}
a+b & b & b & \cdots & \cdots & b \\
-b & a & 0 & 0 & \cdots & \vdots \\
0 & -b & a & 0 & \cdots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & -b & a \\
\end{matrix}
\right|
$$

I figured out that the matrix that is being multiplied by a is just the same matrix of order (n-1)x(n-1) so the recurrence relation is $a_n = b\cdot |B| + a\cdot a_{n-1}$ where $B$ is the matrix on the left

I'm stuck on this last step of trying to figure out the value of $|B|$

Can anyone help?

Comment: ok thank you I will edit my question accordingly

Comment: Let $L$ be the lower triangular matrix of ones. Then $L^{-1}$ is the bidiagonal matrix with ones on the main diagonal and $-1$ on the first sub-diagonal. Therefore your determinant is
$$
\det(aL+bL^T)=\det(L)\det\big(a(L^T)^{-1}+bL^{-1}\big)\det(L^T)
=\det\big(a(L^T)^{-1}+bL^{-1}\big)
$$
is the determinant of the tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix with $a+b$ on the main diagonal, $-b$ on the first sub-digonal and $-a$ on the first super-diagonal. Hence it is given the the linear recurrence relation $d_n=(a+b)d_{n-1}-abd_{n-2}$ with $d_0=1$ and $d_1=a+b$.

Comment: Thank you for the help but I haven't learned this material yet, is there a way to find a recurrence relation using only Elementary operations and the definition of a determinant?

I know how to solve recurrence relations and that the answer is supposed to be $\sum_{i=0}^n a^i\cdot b^{n-i}$

Comment: Have you done expansion by minors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close to the solution of your problem.
The second $n\times n$ determinant with lots of
zeros can be expanded in more than one way.
Perhaps the
easiest is to expand by the first column. The
result is $(a+b)$ times the determinant of
$A_{n-1}$, an $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ lower triangular
matrix with all $a\,$s on the diagonal plus $b$ times the determinant of $B_{n-1}$, an
$(n-1)\times(n-1)$ matrix which is the same
as the lower triangular
matrix except the first row is all $b\,$s.

Let $u_n$ be the determinant of the original
$n\times n$ matrix. The determinant of $A_{n-1}$
is easily $a^{n-1}$. Let $v_{n-1}$ be the
determinant of $B_{n-1}$. Using expansion by
the first column get the recursion
$v_n = ba^{n-1} +bv_{n-1}$ with initial value
$v_1 = b.$  The recursion for $u_n$ is
$u_n = (a+b)a^{n-1} +bv_{n-1}$ with initial
value $u_1 = a+b.$ You can verify that
$u_n = v_n + a^n$ and $v_n = b u_{n-1}$ for
all $n>0.$